# CharSequence equals() does not work well

Tags: java, string, character

Have this code:

```
if (cs.equals(keywordUnderProcess)) {

} else {

}
```

Both `cs` and `keywordUnderProcess` is `CharSequence`, has the value `star`, but the else case will execute. Why? `equals` check the value, isn't it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you read the javadoc page for the [CharSequence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) interface, it says that the behavior for `equals` is undefined:

> This interface does not refine the general contracts of the equals and hashCode methods. The result of comparing two objects that implement CharSequence is therefore, in general, undefined. Each object may be implemented by a different class, and there is no guarantee that each class will be capable of testing its instances for equality with those of the other. It is therefore inappropriate to use arbitrary CharSequence instances as elements in a set or as keys in a map.

Comment: Don't blame an interface for having a bad implementation of an abstract method (unless it has a default method that you blame). In general, don't blame the standard API. If it "does not work well", the problem is usually in the use of it, not the API itself.

Comment: I'm not sure how you got the impression that I was blaming the interface. I am just stating a fact noted by the developers from the documentation.

Comment: Anyway do you know an easy workaround to compare `CharSequence`s? Or convert to `String`, and use `equal` of the `String`?

Comment: Yes, that's the workaround.  Call toString on each of them.

Answer (score 2):

Since Java 11 (released in September 2018) there is a static method `CharSequence.compare` so you can use `if (CharSequence.compare(cs, keywordUnderProcess) == 0)` to compare two CharSequence-s for equality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String#contentEquals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contentEquals-java.lang.CharSequence-) if one the operands is a `String`. If not, you can first call `toString()` on one of them.

In the past, I have lost hours while debugging string equality problems and I am not satisfied by the justification in the [API reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html). As of Java 8, [CharSequence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) could be defined as follows to allow arbitrary `CharSequence`'s to be compared. Classes could then override the default implementation of `equals(CharSequence)` to increase performance, just like what `String` does in `contentEquals()`.

```
public interface CharSequence {
    int length();
    char charAt(int index);
    CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end);
    
    default boolean equals(CharSequence s) {
        if (s == null || length() != s.length())
            return false;
        for (int i = 0; i < length(); i++)
            if (charAt(i) != s.charAt(i))
                return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```